# Disabling the Vertex Editor window in QGIS 2.16

Tags: qgis, editing, qgis-2, user-interface

When I'm editing nodes, the Vertex Editor window is always popping up. As the map is redesigned it is frustrating as I need searching to find the place where I am working. The place where I'm working is always moving in the screen.

Don´t work if I disable `View > Panel > Vertex Editor`.

Comment: A question like this was asked several months ago on the QGIS mailing list: [Possibility to disable Vertex Editor Panel?](http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/Possibility-to-disable-Vertex-Editor-Panel-td5249530.html). Unfortunately, no response.

Answer (score 2):

**Vextex editor** is a dock widget.

[image]

Comment: But when change the tool or deselect the nodes, the panel closes and the screen is redesigned. The screen flashs as the panel appear or disapear... My layer panel is desatacthed.

Comment: for hide the panel you only need,start select node,and the dock appear,and click on `X' in the vertex editor dock and you can continue editing nodes and the dock is hide.

Comment: This dock add in canvas when the tool is activated and you click on canvas. ```https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/master/src/app/nodetool/qgsmaptoolnodetool.cpp#L257```.I thionk that is not possible disapear this panel completely

Comment: Open another panel (such as layers panel or browser panel) and dock it on the side of the screen, as shown in the screenshot above. Now when you use the node tool, the vertex editor panel opens below the existing panel and your map stays the same size.

Answer (score 1):

Disabling the Vertex Editor panel pop-up is now implemented in master version, and should become part of QGIS 3.28

[Add a checkbox to disable vertex tool dock auto-opening behavior](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS-Documentation/issues/7509)

From GitHub QGIS documentation:

> If you do not want the `Vertex Editor` panel to immediately show
> each time you interact with vertex tools (and potentially hide other panels
> or disturb panels placement), uncheck the `Auto-open table` entry
> in the |hamburgerMenu| `Options` menu at the top of the panel.
> You can then also close the panel.
> To reopen the panel, you would need to right-click over a panel or toolbar and
> select it in the list or tick the `Show vertex editor` entry in
> the `Digitizing toolbar`.

Answer (score 0):

Just click the vertex toolbar button twice.